# ¿Cuál es el significado de "discurso" en este contexto?

Tags: acepciones

¿Cuál es el significado de "discurso" en este contexto?

> El objetivo del artículo es analizar la relación entre el **discurso** sobre la práctica pedagógica y la práctica real en sala de clases de los profesores en establecimientos educativos de alto desempeño y bajo nivel socioeconómico de Santiago de Chile. Se implementa un estudio descriptivo de metodología mixta, entrevistas semiestructuradas a nueve docentes, y análisis de filmación de 34 horas de clases. Se encuentra coherencia entre el **discurso** referido al contexto institucional y el tipo de intervención del profesor, y desfase entre el **discurso** sobre la interacción profesor-estudiante y el tipo de intervención con ellos en la clase.
>
> Son dos las preguntas que orientan el estudio: ¿qué elementos del **discurso** constituyen la práctica pedagógica del docente en contextos educativos de alto rendimiento escolar?, y ¿cómo estos elementos discursivos se ponen de manifiesto en la práctica pedagógica en el aula?

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [Spanish.SE]! Tal y como está redactada, la pregunta queda poco clara. Lo que has escrito ¿es parte del texto que no entiendes? ¿Es un texto tuyo? Tal y como está parece que toda la pregunta está copiada del texto que no entiendes, si es así debería aparecer como una cita. Te recomendamos que introduzcas la pregunta con un texto propio, explicando el contexto y la duda que tienes, a continuación pongas la cita, y por último cierres la pregunta con otro texto propio en el que expongas lo que crees que significa "discurso". Así podremos ayudarte mejor. Consulta [ask] para más info.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no muestra ningún tipo de esfuerzo ni explicación

Comment: @CarlosAlejo, gracias por la bienvenida, no imagine que la pregunta no estuviera clara, pero tendre en cuentas las directrices que mencionas para la proxima vez.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parece ser una contraposicion de *discurso* = planteamiento teórico, frente a su implementación en la práctica real.
Efectivamente [**discurso**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DtpVc7a) tiene varias acepciones que indican un planteamiento teórico, como:

> 6. m. Doctrina, ideología, tesis o punto de vista.